# django forms: could not convert string to float

Tags: python, django, forms, django-models, django-forms

I am trying to validate a form using django forms. I have the following model:

```
class Session(models.Model):
    # id = AutoField(primary_key=True) added automatically.
    sport = models.ForeignKey('Sport', unique=False, blank=False, null=False, to_field='sport', on_delete=models.CASCADE, )
    hostplayer = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=False, blank=False, null=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='member_host', )
    guestplayer = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=False, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='member_guest', )
    date = models.DateField(blank=False, null=False, )
    time = models.TimeField(blank=False, null=False, )
    city = models.ForeignKey('City', unique=False, blank=False, null=False, to_field='city', on_delete=models.CASCADE, )
    location = models.CharField(max_length=64, unique=False, blank=False, null=False, )
    price = models.FloatField(unique=False, blank=False, null=False, default=0, )
    details = models.TextField(unique=False, blank=True, null=True, )

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.id)
```

and the following form:

```
class CreateSessionForm(forms.Form):
    sport = forms.CharField()
    date = forms.DateTimeField()
    time = forms.TimeField()
    city = forms.CharField()
    location = forms.CharField()
    price = forms.FloatField(required=False, initial=0, )
    details = forms.CharField(required=False, )

    def clean_price(self):
        prc = self.cleaned_data['price']
        if prc is None:
            return 0
        return prc
```

There is some frontend validation but I want to use the `is_valid()` functionality as well. I have the following piece of code in `views.py`:

```
if request.method == "POST":
    form = CreateSessionForm(data = request.POST)

    if form.is_valid():
        # Create session object.
        session = Session.objects.create(sport=Sport.objects.get(sport = form['sport'].data), hostplayer = request.user, guestplayer = None,
                                         date = form['date'].data, time = form['time'].data, city = City.objects.get(city=form['city'].data),
>>>                                      location = form['location'].data, price = form['price'].data, details = form['details'].data)
        session.save()
        # Return to the session page if successful.
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/session/' + str(session.id) + '/')
```

Everything is working fine, except when the price I receive is `''`. I want to allow this and default to `0`. However, I receive the following error on the line marked with `>>>`:

```
could not convert string to float
```

When debugging that line, it appears that the value of `price` in `form` does not get updated (it appears to be `''`).

**How could I change the value of price in the form to `0` when `''` is passed? What would be the best way to go about doing this?**

I have been searching for a way to fix this for 3 hours now without success. This is the first time I am using forms in django so I may very well be missing something completely obvious.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Fetch the values from `form.cleaned_data`, instead of using `form['fieldname'].data`

For example:

```
date = form.cleaned_data['date']
```

See the docs on [processing the data from a form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/forms/#processing-the-data-from-a-form) for further details.

Answer (score 0):

There might be more than one problem, but the most obvious one that stands out is this:

```
price = modes.FloatField(..., blank=False, ...)
```

in your Session model.

Set blank=True to allow the form field to be blank. The ORM will then use your default=0 when saving if the form field was blank.